# PHP 5.4 times out calling closure

Tags: php, oop, timeout, closures, interceptor

I was just mocking up an intercept class I am working on. Idea is you instantiate the class through the Intercept class and then use that object as if it was the class you are intercepting. A specified callback is then run every time the class gets called. Here is the code:

```
<?php
class Intercept {

    protected $class = null;
    protected $callback = null;

    public function __construct($class, $callback = null) {

        $this->class = new $class();
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    protected function run_callback() {

        $this->callback();
    }

    public function __get($name) {

        $this->run_callback();
        return $this->class->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {

        $this->run_callback();      
        return $this->class->$name = $value;
    }

    public function __isset($name) {

        $this->run_callback();
        return isset($this->class->$name);
    }

    public function __unset($name) {

        $this->run_callback();
        unset($this->class->$name);
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {

        $this->run_callback();
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->class, $method), $args);
    }

    public function __toString() {

        $this->run_callback();
        return $this->class;
    }

    public function __invoke() {

        $this->run_callback();
        return $this->class();
    }
}

class test {
    public function hello() { 
        return 'world'; 
    }
}

$closure = function() {
    echo 123;
};

$test=new Intercept('test', $closure);
echo $test->hello();
```

Now, running the code above **should** display 'world123'. But for some strange reason which I cannot see, it ends up timing out. I tried it on my local machine, and on various php 5.4 tester sites online. Same thing happens. I have narrowed it down to the closure being run ($this->callback()) in the run_callback() method. If i just remove the $this->callback(), it works fine. Why is this happening?

**Edit, while I was writing this question, I figured out that instead of:**

```
$this->callback();
```

Doing this will stop the timeout:

```
$closure = $this->callback;
$closure();
```

It seems that the __call method gets called everytime I try to run the closure directly from the class properties. Is this expected behaviour or have I stumbled apon a PHP bug?

Comment: [Definitely an issue with PHP](http://3v4l.org/qi89N). If you find the cause please do post it here.

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code with xdebug to see what's really going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure it's because you have an infinite loop with the function call stack. When you do

```
$this->callback();
```

You're trying to execute the member function `callback()`, which doesn't exist, so `__call()` gets executed, which tries `callback()` again, which doesn't exist, so `__call()` gets executed, and so on and so forth.

You should be using something along the lines of:

```
call_user_func( $this->callback);
```

Or, like you've edited, this will work too:

```
$closure = $this->callback;
$closure();
```

Hopefully this clears up what is happening. The timeout is just occurring because you're running out of resources (in this case, time). The underlying problem is the infinite loop.